# How would I put ""/'' in a list?

Tags: python, list

Sorry for asking a fairly simple question:

How would I "type" a ""/'' in a list, for example:

```
print("Hello. I am "Playzone"!")

Wanted Output: Hello. I am "Playzone"!

Actual Output: SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

How would I fix this?

Comment: change "Playzone" to \"Playzone\", or just use different quotation marks print('Hello. I am "Playzone"!')

Answer (score 0):

```
print("Hello. I am \"Playzone\"!")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
print("Hello. I am 'Playzon'!")
```

Or

```
 print('''Hello. I am "Playzon"!''')
```